# Trying to pull in elements from Yahoo Weather XML

Tags: php, xml, rss

Trying to pull a value from the sunrise element from [yweather:astronomy] in the Yahoo XML Doc. 
Tried various combinations along the lines of:

```
echo $yweather->astronomy == 'sunrise';
```

Is pulling a value from the sunrise element the right terminology?  Struggling to find much in the way of help using this terminology on the web.

The remainder of the code is functioning as I wish

Yahoo XML Doc - snippet

```
<rss xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" 
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather - New York, NY</title>
    <link>
      http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/New_York__NY/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USNY0996_f.html
    </link>
    <description>Yahoo! Weather for New York, NY</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 12 Dec 2011 1:50 pm EST</lastBuildDate>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <yweather:location city="New York" region="NY" country="US"/>
    <yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
    <yweather:wind chill="40" direction="0" speed="5"/>
    <yweather:atmosphere humidity="37" visibility="10" pressure="30.54" rising="2"/>
    <yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:09 am" sunset="4:26 pm"/>
```

rssweather.php

```
<?php

// Get XML data from source
$feed = file_get_contents("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USNY0996&u=f");

// Check to ensure the feed exists
if(!$feed){
die('Weather not found! Check feed URL');
}

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

foreach ($xml->channel as $entry){
    echo "<strong>Description</strong> "; 
    echo $entry->description; 
    echo "<br /><strong>Collected on</strong> ";
    echo $entry->lastBuildDate;

    //Use that namespace
    $yweather = $entry->children("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
    echo "<br /><strong>Sunrise</strong> ";
    echo $yweather->astronomy == 'sunrise';

}
>?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution

```
// Get and return sunrise time 
function get_sunrise_time(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {
    $weather['sunrise'] = $xml->channel->children('yweather', TRUE)->astronomy[1]->attributes()->sunrise;

    return $weather;
}
```